# finding position of element of a vector that satisfies given condition in c++

Tags: python, c++, pointers, vector, stdvector

I am learning c++, and I want to implement the following python codes in c++:

```py
C = np.where(A > B)[0]
while len(C) > 0:
    d = C[0]
    # do something to A[d] and B[d]
    C = A > B
```

`A` and `B` are both vectors of the same length. In C++, I know how to declare and initialize `A` and `B` using `vector`, and implement the middle "do something part" to both A and B, but I don't know how to compare them and check if `A` has elements larger than `B`, and find the index of the element where this occurs.

Comment: The `<algorithm>` header has a [`mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) function that can tell you where they differ.

Comment: what if I only need to know if `A` is larger than `B`? Is there a similar function as `mismatch`? I don't care if `A` is smaller `B`.

Answer (score 6):

C++ has a rich set of utility functions in [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header. In case of your problem:

- `C = np.where(A>B)[0]` could be translated to C++ as follows:

  ```
  std::size_t index = 0;
  auto pos = std::find_if(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), [&index, &B](const int &i){
      return i > B[index++];
  });
  ```
- `C = A>B` also could be rewritten in C++ as follows:

  ```
  std::size_t index = 0;
  auto is_okay = std::all_of(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), [&index, &B](const int &i){
      return i > B[index++];
  });
  ```

So, it altogether could be simplified as below:

```
std::vector<int> A = {/* contents of A */};
std::vector<int> B = {/* contents of B */};

std::size_t index;
auto greaterThanB = [&index, &B](const int &i){
    return i > B[index++];
};

// C = np.where(A>B)[0]
index = 0;
auto pos = std::find_if(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), greaterThanB);

// C = A>B
index = 0;
auto is_okay = std::all_of(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), greaterThanB);
```

Also note that in this code `pos` is of type `vector<int>::iterator` which points to the first match. In order to convert it to an integer index, you can use `std::distance` function.

```
std::size_t index = std::distance(A.cbegin(), pos);
```

Comment: While I cannot currently think of why this would happen in practice, I think there's no guarantee in the standard that `std::find_if` or `std::all_of` will not call their predicate more often.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I just tried to translate those Python lines to C++. Also considering `std::find_if` or `std::all_of`, the predicate is checked once for each item, so this assures us the `index` is set properly.